# parallely processing the messages from a queue

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

i have the below program which consumes messages from queue and the queue is tibco queue , now i am trying to develop an utility lets say
sometimes an situation comes in which some external application sends lots of messages on this queue for example somewhere around 20,000 messages in a day  now we have a legacy code written in java which simple consumes the messages and write to a file named messagesday.txtand write all the messages of queue in that file and store it in a c drive of the computer

now i want to enhance this as this legacy utility takes lots of time in consuming the messages so i have chosen the spring integration in technology , in spring integration i have come up with this below  on xml in which it is simply consuming the messages from queue rite now

plese advise how can i add concurrent consumers in it so that multiple consumers can listen to the same queue at a time and then write the messages of the queue to a text file and save it in  c drive of my computer

folks please advise

```
     <int:channel id="output"  > 
  </int:channel>

<bean id="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
<property name="environment">
<props>
<prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</prop>
<prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://ftr.net:7833</prop>
<prop key="java.naming.security.principal">rtey</prop>
<prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">rtey</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSConnFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>GenericConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

 <bean id="tibcosendJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref local="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDestinationName">
            <value>rtey.dev.queue.test.data</value>
        </property>         
        <property name="pubSubDomain">
            <value>false</value> 
        </property>
        <property name ="receiveTimeout">
            <value>120000</value>
        </property> 
    </bean>    


    <int:channel id="input">
<int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>

<jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="input" destination-name="rtey.dev.queue.test.data"  connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" /> 

<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter channel="output" destination-name="rtey.dev.queue.test.data" connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory"   /> 

</beans>
```

Comment: Doesn't `concurrent-consumers` option on the `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` help you? We have an open issue for `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>`, which should provide better throughput for writing to the same file, BTW.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks a lot for your advise just one quick query shall i add an attribute to <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter> lets say like <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter concurrent-consumers =8 , i am new bie to the spring integration it will be a great help if you could please do changes in my above xml , it will help me a lot and i will grasp more,Thanks in advance , altough i have visited to this url also after your advise pls ..http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/128489-enable-multithreading-in-jms-message-driven-channel-adapter

Comment: Yes, that topic is good, too. Please, read more docs on the matter: https://spring.io/ and use some modern IDE, which can suggest you attributes for auto-completion.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks  for your advise well since i am new to the spring integration so i am using eclipse juno and have installed STS plugin suite in it a and it shows me the xml in graphical format also like integration graph  , but the major concern was only lets say if some external process put 40,000 messages in queue in a day and i have to consume them as fast as possible in order to make queue empty as soon as possible then i think this is the best solution , please advise if there any other best solution mite be available in spring integration itself

Comment: @ArtemBilan anyways this url is the best one it had answered all my queries perfectly http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/109765-concurrent-consumers-in-context-to-spring-integration